# Trouble with a Hoffman Kunze Exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

I've just started with Linear Algebra, on my own, and I'm facing some difficulty in the first problem set. It'd be great if you could help me out!

The question says, *Prove that each field of characteristic zero contains a copy of the rational number field*

I understand that this question has been asked on Math SE earlier, but the answers posted do not clarify some of my doubts.

1. What do they mean by *a copy* of the rational number field? Are they saying that Q is a subfield of the field in discussion?
2. 1 and 0, multiplicative and additive inverses must exist in the field. Now, what do I do from here? (I think I've probably not understood what characteristic has to do with, exactly, because I don't ever see 1 + 1 + .... 1 amounting to zero, isn't it always a positive number?)

I believe it is sufficient to prove that the field in discussion is a subfield of the complex number field, because we know that every subfield of C must contain Q.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A copy of the rational numbers" means there is a subfield that is **isomorphic** to the rational numbers.  It does not  have to be the actual rational numbers. Yes, 1+ 1+ 1+ … is never 0.  That is what "characteristic 0" **means**!

Comment: How can 1+1+1+.. = 0 if the characteristic is not zero? Should I just wait for the mystery to unfold over time in the book?

Comment: Consider the field of integers modulo 5 (more generally modulo any prime number). Then 1+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 1= 5= 0 (mod 5).  The field of integers modulo p where p is a prime number has characteristic p.